# Minimum and maximum of $f(x,y)=\text{sin(x)+cos(y)}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How can I find the extremum points of the function $f(x,y)=sinx+cosy$ in $S=[0,2\pi]\text{X} [0,2\pi]$?

I found that the critical points in the interior of the square are : $({\pi\over 2}, \pi), ({3\pi\over2}, \pi)$ but the hessian matrix in these points is zero

Is there any other way to know if this points are extremum points?

Comment: The max is obviously 2 (1+1), the min -2. Are you searching extremum or critical points ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, since $-2 \leq \sin x+\cos y \leq 2$ for all $x,y$ just calculating $f$ in the critical points should give you the answer this time.

Also check your values, those do not seem to be correct. Maybe you meant $(\pi/2, 0)$...? (also there are more).